# Find part of string matches with other string SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a value assigned in variable say @var1 = '3,5,6,8'. I have a table which has column with some random numbers combination as comma separated. PFB sample table

[image]

I need all values of the table except Id 3 since it has 9 in its combination '3,9,8'.

I would like to have the response as follows.

Expected  Output should contain only the IDs 1,2 and 4.

The reason is, any/all of the values present in @var1 should be present in Nos and it should not have a no which is not present in @var1. Id 3 is an example for the latter case which contains 9 which is not part of @var1.

My output should have Ids 1,2 and 4 and not 3.

Could you please suggest some ideas to do it?

Comment: You should be passing these 4 values through as different parameters. If you don't then you're going to need to split this data out before running a NOT LIKE

Comment: Pl. be little clear what you need! In the first line, @Var1 has 3, 5, 6 and 8. but in the last line you said it has 9 in @Var1!!

Comment: Do yourself a great big favor and normalize your database as soon as possible. A Comma delimited string is **NOT** a valid data type!

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Thanks. This is not actual table stored in the DB but a temp table created for comparison purpose where comma separated data is obtained as a stuffing of actual data from the table.

Comment: Good. Then it will be easier to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cast to xml and use xquery:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = '37,39,41,43' 
DECLARE @table TABLE(Id INT, Nos VARCHAR(max)) 
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1,'37,35,46'),(2,'37,38'),(3,'39,40'),(4,'37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46') 

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE cast('<n>' + replace(@var1,',','</n><n>') + '</n>' AS XML).exist('//n/.[not(contains(sql:column("nos"),.))]') = 0 
UNION
SELECT * FROM @table WHERE cast('<n>' + replace(Nos,',','</n><n>') + '</n>' AS XML).exist('//n/.[not(contains(sql:variable("@var1"),.))]') = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But is not working as expected. I have tried the follwoing: `DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100) = '37,39,41,43'
DECLARE @table TABLE(Id INT, Nos VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES(1,'37,35,46'),(2,'37,38'),(3,'39,40'),(4,'37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46')

SELECT * 
FROM @table
WHERE cast('<n>' + replace(Nos,',','</n><n>') + '</n>' AS XML).exist('//n/.[not(contains(sql:variable("@var1"),.))]')  = 0`

Comment: when I run it, it returns no rows which I expected because in each there is at least one number that is not in the list; is it not what you need? what output do you expect from this sample?

Comment: I expected (4,'37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46' ) because all the values (37, 39, 41, 43)  of @var1 present in 4th record.

Comment: but that is not consistent with your original question where var1= '3,5,6,8' and none of the records have those 4 values present in column 'nos', however you expected three rows returned because all their 'nos' values where in var1. Could you please clarify which way do you want the subset test:  var1 as a subset of 'nos' or 'nos' as a subset of var1?

Comment: I ve updated my question. Please have a look at it and provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Ok, I see, you basically need to compare both ways, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can still be further reduced but the idea is as follows,

Create a SplitString function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

Use the below series of queries and customize it,

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, Nos VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT @t
VALUES (1,
        '5, 3'), (2,
                  '3, 6, 8'), (3,
                               '3, 9, 8'),(4,
                                           '8') IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
SELECT * INTO #Temp
FROM
  (SELECT ID,
          LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Nos
   FROM
     (SELECT ID,
             CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Nos,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
      FROM @t)t CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)) P
SELECT '3, 5, 6, 8'
SELECT '(1==> 5, 3), (2==> 3, 6, 8), (3 ==> 3, 9, 8),(4 ==> 8)'
SELECT *
FROM #Temp
SELECT Item
FROM dbo.SplitString('3, 5, 6, 8', ',')
SELECT '-- Group By '
SELECT Id,
       Count(Nos) C
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY Id
SELECT Id,
       Count(Nos) C
FROM
  (SELECT Item
   FROM dbo.SplitString('3, 5, 6, 8', ',')) X
JOIN
  (SELECT Id,
          Nos
   FROM #Temp) Y ON X.Item = Y.Nos
GROUP BY Id
SELECT '-- Final check'
SELECT T.*
FROM
  (SELECT Id,
          Count(Nos) C
   FROM #Temp
   GROUP BY Id) P
JOIN
  (SELECT Id,
          Count(Nos) C
   FROM
     (SELECT Item
      FROM dbo.SplitString('3, 5, 6, 8', ',')) X
   JOIN
     (SELECT Id,
             Nos
      FROM #Temp) Y ON X.Item = Y.Nos
   GROUP BY Id) Q ON P.Id = Q.Id
AND P.C = Q.C
JOIN #Temp T ON T.Id = P.Id
```